# Upload an artifact returns 201 but nothing created

Tags: nexus

I have a project that I want to upload from a `Windows` machine. It's not `Java`, so I can't use `Maven`.

Is there a `Windows` batch or `PowerShell` script I can use to accomplish this? Here's what I have and it works

The POST returns 201, but nothing gets created on the nexus repository.

Note the input file is <20 characters and is in the same directory as the powershell script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without seeing the parameters you are sending I can't tell you what is wrong.

See here for information on what parameters are needed:

https://support.sonatype.com/entries/22189106-How-can-I-programatically-upload-an-artifact-into-Nexus-

Also check the nexus.log, there may be more information there about this error.